# Angle of a triangle in a cube

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, 3d, angle

> Find the angle of a triangle in a cube. [image]

I don't how to start on this problem. The only I have noticed is that it may be a isosceles triangle so the two angle should be the same.

Can somebody give me hints on how to solve it?

Comment: You can use vectors approach for this, all you need is the points coordinates and the dot product.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint : the triangle is equilateral...

Comment: If it were so, the angle should be 60°C and not 75°C. But the website with the answers stated that 75°C is the correct one.

Comment: Don't you see that all the sides of the triangle are a diagonal of a side of your cube, so they have the same lenght ?

Comment: Yeah, I see it. Thank you for clarifying it. But the website had it wrong then.

Comment: Don't always trust what you read :)